# How to write a unit test with mockito in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I'm a newbie in Python and I have problem with mockito in Python.

My production code looks like below:

```
from stompest.config import StompConfig
from stompest.sync import Stomp


class Connector:
    def sendMessage(self):
        message = {'message'}
        dest = '/queue/foo'

    def _send(self, message='', dest=''):
        config = StompConfig(uri="tcp://localhost:61613")
        client = Stomp(config)
        client.connect()
        client.send(body=message, destination=dest,
                    headers='')
        client.disconnect()
```

as you see I would like to send a message using Stomp protocol. I my test I would like to test that w when I invoke a send method from Connector class a send method from Stompest library will be only once invoked.

My unit test looks like:

```
from Connector import Connector

import unittest
from mockito import *
import stompest
from stompest.config import StompConfig
from stompest.sync import Stomp


class test_Connector(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_shouldInvokeConnectMethod(self):
        stomp_config = StompConfig(uri="tcp://localhost:61613")
        mock_stomp = mock(Stomp(stomp_config))

        connector = Connector()
        connector.sendMessage()
        verify(mock_stomp, times=1).connect()
```

When I run test in debug mode I see that method for instance connect() is invoked and method send as well, but as a result of test I get:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\development\systemtest_repo\robot_libraries\test_Connector.py", line 16, in test_shouldInvokeConnectMethod
    verify(mock_stomp, times=1).connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mockito\invocation.py", line 111, in __call__
    verification.verify(self, len(matched_invocations))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mockito\verification.py", line 63, in verify
    raise VerificationError("\nWanted but not invoked: %s" % (invocation))
VerificationError: 
Wanted but not invoked: connect()
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually call the `connect` method on the mock object - you just check that it was called. This is what the error says as well `Wanted but not invoked: connect()`. Perhaps adding a call to `mock_stomp.connect()` before the call to `verify` will fix this:

```
mock_stomp = mock(Stomp(stomp_config))

# call the connect method first...
mock_stomp.connect()

connector = Connector()
connector.sendMessage()

# ...then check it was called
verify(mock_stomp, times=1).connect()
```

If you are instead trying to check that the mock is called from `Connector`, you probably at least need to pass in the `mock_stomp` object via dependency injection. For example

```
class Connector:
  def __init__(self, stomp):
   self.stomp = stomp

  def sendMessage(self, msg):
    self.stomp.connect()
    # etc ...
```

and in your test

```
mock_stomp = mock(Stomp(stomp_config))
connector = Connector(mock_stomp)
connector.sendMessage()

verify(mock_stomp, times=1).connect()
```

Otherwise, I don't see how the `connect()` method could be invoked on the same instance of `mock_stomp` that you are basing your assertions on.